# How to access with WebView local content (HTML/JS) on the device?

Tags: ionic-framework, webview, capacitor

I need to understand how can WebView access HTML/JS/images which are stored locally on the device. This content is on the device because my own Ionic app downloaded them there (I don't need to access content which is not mine).

I tried WebView, but by default it can only access content from the internet.